# SAS If conditional before PROC SORT

Tags: sorting, if-statement, sas

```
if &var. not in ('quarter' 'period' 'year') then do;
    proc sort data=test_&var.;
        by descending column1;
    run;
end;
```

I'm trying to attach a conditional statement before a proc sort statement, but I'm having trouble getting the IF to work outside of a data step. Is there some way around this?

Basically I don't want to sort any test_&var. datasets that contain a time variable as those are the only datasets I want to retain a particular sequence in.

Comment: You need to use macro logic instead of if/then it becomes %if %then, but you also need to use a macro entirely to wrap it in.

Comment: Yep @Reeza I tried that but returns an error saying "A character operand was found in the  operand is required."

Is there some extra code needed to have SAS read the if statement with a macro variable correctly?

Comment: The answer below is pretty thorough. In general though if you say something doesn't work without showing any code you're not likely to get any help since we have no idea of what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a macro example:

```
/* tell macro language to recognise the in operator */
options minoperator;

/* demo data */
data test_yymm; column1=1;run;
data test_quarter; column1=1;run;

%macro demo(var) ;
/* remove quotes, place not outside the condition */
%if not (&var in quarter period year) %then %do;
    proc sort data=test_&var.;
        by descending column1;
    run;
%end;
%mend;

/* call macro */
%demo(yymm);
%demo(quarter);
```

You could also achieve this in a data step, by calling `call execute`:

```
%let var=yymm;
data _null_;
  if "&var" not in ('quarter' 'period' 'year') then do;
    call execute("
      proc sort data=test_&var.;
        by descending column1;
      run;
    ");
  end;
run;
```

Remember that SAS macro language is text based, so variables do not need to be quoted.  Unlike regular SAS code, in which string literals DO need to be quoted in order to be recognised as such..

Comment: Very nice, did not know about that `option` !

Good nice tips and tricks here to nest proc steps in a data step too. Cheers.